# Changing the order of $dy,dx$ when $y$ is a function of $x$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

If we have a double integral $\int_{a}^{b} \int_{h(x)}^{g(x)} f(x,y) dydx$,can we swap the orders and limits by $\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)} \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y) dxdy$? I am saying this because when the limits of both variables are numbers (unlike limits like $h(x),g(x)$ for $y$ in this case),we could swap the order. Is it possible to do the same in this case?

Comment: Draw a set for the first integral on the plane and look at it when the legs are on the vertical axis and the head is directed along the horizontal axis.

Comment: The second “integral” has no meaning

Comment: How would you integrate $g(x), h(x),f(x,y)$ wrt $x$ all at once in $\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)} \int_a^b f(x,y) dxdy$?

Answer (score 2):

We are allowed to apply Fubini's theorem on general regions. If $f(x,y)$ is continuous on a region
$R=\{(x,y) \, : \, a\le x \le b, \, \varphi_1(x) \le y \le \varphi_2(x) \} \,$ and
$R=\{(x,y) \, : \, \alpha\le y \le \beta, \, \psi_1(x) \le x \le \psi_2(x) \}, \,$ then
$$
\iint_R f(x,y) \, \mathrm dS = \int_a^b\int_{\varphi_1(x)}^{\varphi_2(x)}f(x,y)\, \mathrm dy \, \mathrm dx = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \int_{\psi_1(y)}^{\psi_2(y)}f(x,y) \, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm dy.
$$

[image]